# jQuery date / time picker setting default time doesn't set to what I specify?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

**background**

I'm trying to set the default date and default time for this jquery plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/2010/04/19/timepicker-addon-for-jquery-ui-datepicker/

**problem**

The times change, but not to the value I specify. For example, for date I pass in a value of `2013-12-16`, and it changes it to `12-16-2013`. Timepicker is similar, I pass in `'03:00:00'` and it changes it to `8:00AM`

**The Code**

The values are retrieved as strings from PHP.

```
$('#appointmentTime').timepicker({
       controlType: 'select',
       timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
       ampm: true, 
       step: '15'
   });
$('#appointmentTime').timepicker('setTime', '<?echo $ascStudent->get("nextAppointmentTime")?>' );                                       
$('#appointmentDate').datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'});
$('#appointmentDate').datepicker('defaultDate', '<?echo $ascStudent->get("nextAppointmentDate")?>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Default date does not work datepicker despite some other SO answers (or at least not in my case). It also apparently needs to be pre-formatted for the widget, like so:

```
$('#appointmentDate').datepicker('setDate', '<?echo date("m-d-Y", strtotime(str_replace("-","/", $ascStudent->get("nextAppointmentDate")))); ?>');
```